# Text color inverting on selection

Tags: android, textview, textcolor, android-selector

I have a multichoice ListView whose items have a light (transparent) background by default and a dark one while selected. Therefore, I would like to have the TextViews in the items change their color accordingly, i.e. black by default and white while selected.

Obviously, I can manually define a selector that does this, but is there some predefined color or style in the Android SDK that I could use out of the box?

Just for illustration, the navigation drawer in Gmail does this:

[image]